# ¿Como quito la ventana de sugerencia de visual studio code?

Tags: vscode

tengo un problema, no se que opción tengo que cambiar para que VSCode deje de mostrarme este menú:
[image: Menu que quiero eliminar]

Lo que me molesta es que esto aparezca de modo que a veces impide incluso ver el código que escribo.

Comment: desactiva el plugin que hace eso...